# Code for at two-way sliding panel using HTML5

Tags: html

I'm looking for code or a plugin for a sliding panel that can slide both ways using HTML5.

Example website: http://mckinney.com/

I'm not a programmer and am using Dreamweaver. Is there any code I can copy and paste to help do this?

Answer (score 0):

not really a copy paste thing.. can simulate this with jQuery. Here is an example tutorial which you can follow to re-produce that effect. [slide viewer](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/imagestrip/imageslide-plugin.html)